# how to edit file content programmatically in android

Tags: java, android, file, file-handling

I want to change text already written in a file programmatically using android application.
For example file name is myFile which contains

some text.
This is a sample:"p".

Now I want to replace "p" with "c".

Comment: general strategy can be: read whole file using some buffer into some variable of type e.g string or stringbuilder make modification on this variable, and then write the whole content of it into file. Examples how to in java: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-io-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Scanner class to load the file, line by line. Look for the desired string and replace it with what you want.